# threadpool c++ implementation questions

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

[here](https://github.com/dabbertorres/ThreadPool) and [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool) , we can see similar threadpool implementations.

my question is about function to add the task to threadpool, these are **add** and **enqueue** in projects above respectively.

because these look very similar I'm posting a piece of one here (from second project)

```
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
-> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
        std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    );

    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

    // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
        if(stop)
            throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");

        tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); });
    }
    condition.notify_one();
    return res;
}
```

container **tasks** declared as :

```
std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;
```

so my questions are:

1. why tasks declared with additional wrapper std::function around **task** variable ? why a
       queue of the tasks is not declared as a container of
       std::packaged_task which is also a callable object? I suppose that
       queue of the tasks should contains "universal" callable objects
       without parameters and without return type. so the removing
       parameters achieved by the binding, and extra wrapper std::function
       assists to remove return type, is it correct or no? also about the using of shared_ptr - is it only to avoid a collision that packaged_task is movable type but std::function is a copyable  ?
2. is it a good practice to use one shared task queue for all threads ?
   I'm looking at Anthony Williams "C++ Concurrency in action" he
   recommends to avoid this to prevent cache line contention. and he
   recommends to use more advanced technique with two levels of queue -
   global and thread_local for worker's threads.

Comment: I see a lot of "stars" and rate "ups" . in other case , I see the suggestions to close this. guys (who votes to close) , please use a comments to explain what is wrong/incorrect in a question , otherwise looks you simply don't understand the question/problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are still looking for an answer (you mostly answered it on your own):

1. Exactly as you supposed.
2. It's not "not good practice". It just leads to a performance drop, not only due to cache line contention, but also because of contention on the task list.

Current HPC thread pool implementations mostly use a work stealing scheduler: Each worker has its own queue. The worker pulls and pushes work from/to his own queue, until he has finished all the tasks in its own queue. Then it steals tasks from other workers and executes those.